# shortcut for moving from type tool to move tool - photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shortcuts, type

Moving from the type tool to the move tool in photoshop I don't know how to do. I have tried option+command+shift+k but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Ermm.. `t` for the type tool... `v` for the move tool. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you're trying to do, but if you're editing some text with the Type tool <kbd>T</kbd>, you first need to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stop editing with the Type tool, before hitting <kbd>V</kbd> for Move tool.

Or just use your mouse and click the Type/Move icons in the main toolbar.

Comment: On a Mac with extended keyboard, Enter [not Return] works too, to leave text editing.

Answer (score 0):

press CTRL+Enter, then press v